# How to clear TextBoxes nested inside a TabControl, TabPage and 2 Panels?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox, tabcontrol

The picture below represents a plug-in I am building.

**Yellow** = tabControl1; **Orange** = tabPage1; **Blue** = Main Panel (mainPanel); **Green** = 3 different panels inside the main panel (panel1, panel2 and panel3); **White** = TextBoxes (that I want to clear); **DarkBlue** = CheckBoxes corresponsing to the green panels

[image: plugIn]

I am trying to clear any text from the TextBoxes that contain text and reset CheckBoxes when checked, with a **button click.**

I researched online and tried to accomplish this by the following way but it doesn't seem to be the correct way to handle this problem.

```
foreach (Control a in tabControl1.Controls)
{
    foreach(Control b in tabPage1.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in mainPanel.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control d in panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (d is TextBox)
                {
                    d.Text = " ";
                }
                if (d is CheckBox)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)d).Checked = false; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have only shown `panel1` here but tried doing the same thing for `panel2` and 3 as well.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the `TextBox`es and `ComboBox`es inside of `panel1` then you only need to loop through `panel1`'s controls to do it. To handle any panel, you could just write a `ClearPanel(Panel)` function.

```csharp
private void ClearPanel(Panel panel)
{
   foreach (var ctrl in panel.Controls)
   {
      if (ctrl is TextBox tb)
      {
         tb.Clear();
      }
      else if (ctrl is CheckBox chkBx)
      {
         chkBx.Checked = false;
      }
   }
}

private void ClearPanel1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClearPanel(panel1);
}
```

Iterating through the controls in `tabControl1`, `tabPage1`, etc, etc adds unnecessary overhead if you already have a reference to the `Panel` you're dealing with. What's more, if any of the controls in the outer loops have an empty `Controls` collection then the inner loops won't execute. I suspect this might be why your code isn't working.

Note that the above solution will not handle any `TextBox` or `ComboBox` that is inside another container inside `panel1`. So, if `panel1` had a `GroupBox` inside it which contained `TextBox`es or `ComboBox`es, they wouldn't be cleared. See the recursive solution below to handle that situation.

**EDIT: After re-reading your question I thought maybe you want to clear all `TextBox` and `CheckBox` controls on the `Form`.**

If you're needing to clear every `TextBox` or `CheckBox` on the `Form`, you can do this with recursion.

```csharp
private void Clear(Control ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox tb)
    {
       tb.Clear();
    }
    if (ctrl is CheckBox chkBx)
    {
       chkBx.Checked = false;
    }
    foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
    {
       Clear(child);
    }
}

private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Clear(this);
}
```

You could pass any `Control` to `Clear(Control)`, so if you only wanted to do the `TextBox`es and `ComboBox`es on `tabPage1` you could call `Clear(tabPage1)`. This will clear all the `TextBox`es and `ComboBox`es on `tabPage1`, even if they're in a `Panel` or `GroupBox` or some other container.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a simple recursive method that iterates all controls inside all child containers of a specified parent container, **`mainPanel`**, here.
If a control is of type TextBox or CheckBox, set its `Text` or `Checked` property accordingly:

(Note that you can also pass `tabPage1` to the method, or any other ancestor)

```
ClearControls(panel1);
// or
ClearControls(tabPage1);
```

```
private void ClearControls(Control parent)
{
    if ((parent == null) || (!parent.HasChildren))
        return;
    foreach (var ctl in parent.Controls.OfType<Control>())
    {
        if (ctl is TextBox txt) {
            txt.Clear();
        }
        if (ctl is CheckBox chk) {
            chk.Checked = false;
        }
        else {
            if (ctl.HasChildren) {
                ClearControls(ctl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```